# Compare the Restored MS-SQL DBs against the original DB using python

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using an external utility for backing up my MS-SQL dbs, which takes the backup of my dbs and on restoring it gives me the db files (.mdf, .ldf) files.

Now, what I need is, to verify whether the Restored db files(.mdf &.ldf files) are same as the original db files or not using `Python` for automation. Is there any utility which does the db comparison that can be integrated with python?

I am looking into [pymssql](http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/intro.html) module, but not sure, if I can compare the restored DBs using this module...

Answer (score 0):

I had a look into `pymssql`. What `pymssql` does is, just execute the SQL query passed to it and return the output of the same. But, the installation of `pymssql` (on windows) is really a very difficult task. So, instead of using `pymssql`, I preferred using the in-built `SQLCMD` utility of SQL server to execute my SQL query.

So, I used `os.system()` of `python` to execute my SQL query via `SQLCMD`. Therefore, I wrote my SQL query into an .sql file through python, then pass it to SQLCMD and redirected the output to another text file.

SO using SQLCMD, I first, gathered the list of tables in the given database. Then, I queried all the tables one by one and dropped the data of them into one single text file `(Original_DB_Data.txt)`. For the restored db also, I followed the same procedure and dumped the data to another text file `(Restored_DB_Data.txt)`. The code snippet is as follow :-

```
    import os
    def get_table_list_in_DB(Instance_name, DB_name):

        query = 'SELECT NAME from [%s].sys.tables' %(DB_name)
        input_file = "C:\\SQL_Data\\SQLQuery_table_list.sql"
        output_file = "C:\\SQL_Data\\Table_list_DB-%s_Output.txt" %(DB_name)

        with open(input_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(query)

        command = 'sqlcmd -S %s -i %s -o %s' %(Instance_name, input_file, output_file)
        os.system(command)
        os.remove(input_file) # to delete the created .sql file
        return output_file


    def get_db_data(Instance_name, DB_name):

        output_file = "C:\\SQL_Data\\DB_Data-%s_Output.txt" %(DB_name)
        table_list = get_table_list_in_DB(Instance_name, DB_name)

        flag = 0
        with open(table_list, 'r') as f1, open(output_file, 'a') as f2:
            for lines in f1:
                if re.match("^\s", lines):
                    flag = 0
                if flag:
                    table_data = get_table_data(Instance_name, DB_name, table_name=lines.strip())
                    with open(table_data, 'r') as f3:
                        f2.write("##################################" + '\n')
                        f2.write('\t' +lines.strip() + '\n')
                        f2.write("##################################" + '\n')
                        f2.write(f3.read())
                    os.remove(table_data)
                if re.match("^----+", lines):
                    flag = 1
        return output_file


    def get_table_data(Instance_name, DB_name, table_name):

        input_file = "C:\\SQL_Data\\SQLQuery_table_data.sql"
        output_file = "C:\\SQL_Data\\Table_data_%s_Output.txt" %(table_name)

        query = "SELECT * from [%s].dbo.[%s]" %(DB_name, table_name)

        with open(input_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(query)

        command = "sqlcmd -S %s -i %s -o %s" %(Instance_name, input_file, output_file)
        os.system(command)
        os.remove(input_file)
        return output_file

  def compare_DB_Data(DB_Detail1=[], DB_Detail2=[]):
      get_db_data(Instance_name=DB_Detail1[0], DB_name=DB_Detail1[1])
      get_db_data(Instance_name=DB_Detail2[0], DB_name=DB_Detail2[1])

      data_DB1 = "C:\\SQL_Data\\DB_Data-%s_Output.txt" %(DB_Detail1[1])
      data_DB2 = "C:\\SQL_Data\\DB_Data-%s_Output.txt" %(DB_Detail2[1])

      with open(data_DB1, 'r') as f1, open(data_DB2, 'r') as f2:
          if f1.read() == f2.read():
              print "Data of both DB Matches"
          else:
              print "Data of both DB Varies"
```

In case, you want to improve the `compare_DB_Data()` method so as to get what is the exact difference, then you can re-write it as follows, which will dump the difference into another text file and you can later on refer it so as to check what exactly is the difference :-

```
def compare_DB_Data(DB_Detail1=[], DB_Detail2=[]):
    '''
    This method collects the data from both the given db and then compares the data
    If any difference found, it appends the same into a file for post-verification
    '''

    get_db_data(Instance_name=DB_Detail1[0], DB_name=DB_Detail1[1])
    get_db_data(Instance_name=DB_Detail2[0], DB_name=DB_Detail2[1])

    data_DB1 = "C:\\SQL_Data\\DB_Data-%s_Output.txt" %(DB_Detail1[1])
    data_DB2 = "C:\\SQL_Data\\DB_Data-%s_Output.txt" %(DB_Detail2[1])
    data_difference = "C:\\SQL_Data\\Data-Difference-%s-vs-%s_Output.txt" %(DB_Detail1[1], DB_Detail2[1])

    with open(data_difference, 'w') as f3:
        f3.write("Data Difference in %s vs %s \n" %(DB_Detail1[1], DB_Detail2[1]))
        f3.write("-"*100 + '\n')
        f3.write(DB_Detail1[1])
        f3.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t')
        f3.write(DB_Detail2[1] + '\n')
        f3.write("-"*100 + '\n')

    data_diff =0
    with open(data_DB1, 'r') as f1, open(data_DB2, 'r') as f2:
        for line_f1, line_f2 in zip(f1, f2):
            if line_f1 != line_f2:
                data_diff = 1    # Flag set if any difference found
                with open(data_difference, 'a') as f3:
                    f3.write(line_f1.strip() + '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t' + line_f2.strip())

    if data_diff:
        print "Data of both DB Varies"
    else:
        print "Data of both DB Matches"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer intentionally. The above answer will work only if ran on the same machine, where SQL server is residing. And, earlier we were using text file, which doesn't ensure the complete comparison between the two dbs. So, this new one is a dictionary based approach to avoid the above issue.

The below code works even if your SQL server and your code are on different machines. But, for that you need to enable the `WINRM` module on the machine where SQL server is present. `WINRM` is a window's in-built module, for communicating between windows machine. For enabling the WINRM on a machine you need to run the following commands in the command line of the SQL machine.

```
winrm qc -q
winrm set winrm/config/client/auth @{Basic="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
```

This would enable WINRM module on your machine. Now we will need `pywinrm` module of python for the communication with our remote SQL host. Refer [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinrm) link for installation of `pywinrm`.

So, here first we will collect the list of tables present in the database (used the method `get_table_list_in_DB`. Store those tables into a text file. This list will be used both for collecting table schema as well as table data for all the tables existing on the database. Read each table name from the file one by one and query for table schema and table data.

The `get_db_Schema()` method reads the above returned table list and internally calls the `get_table_Schema()` method, collects the schema details for all the tables inside the database. The schema returned for each table are stored as dictionary key-value pair, where the table name is the key and the returned schema is value. So the whole db schema is a dictionary with each table as `key` and their schema as `value`.

In the same way, `get_db_data()` and `get_table_data()` works. `get_db_data()` collects the data for each table and stores in a dictionary with table name as `key` and the returned data as `value` for the same.

So to compare two databases, we pass the database details (DB name and instance name) to `compare_DB_Data()` method, which in turn, calls the  `get_db_Schema()` for both the databases and compares them. If schema for both the databases matches, then in will call `get_db_data()` method for both the databases and matches them. Since, we have stored table schema as well as table data in form of key-value pair, so if each key from DB1 (both for schema as well as data) has the same value in both the DBs, then we can ensure that both our DBs are same.

In case any difference in schema of both DB found, those are added to `schema1_diff_schema2` `schema2_diff_schema1` dictionary. Likewise, data difference are added to `data1_diff_data2` and `data2_diff_data1` dictionaries.

Below is the code piece for the same :-

```
class SQL_Compare_DB(object):

    def __init__(self, SQL_Host_IP, auth):
        # Append to path, in case not present
        sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn")
        # Create session with SQL host
        self.session = winrm.Session(SQL_Host_IP, auth)
        # We need a directory where the db files will be stored
        if not os.path.exists("C:\SQL_Data"):
            os.mkdir("C:\SQL_Data")
        else:
            os.system("RMDIR /S /Q C:\SQL_Data")
            os.system("MKDIR C:\SQL_Data")


    def get_table_list_in_DB(self, Instance_name, DB_name):
        '''
        Returns the list of table in the given database
        '''
        output_file = "C:\\SQL_Data\\Table_list_DB-%s_Output.txt" %(DB_name)

        query = 'SELECT NAME from [%s].sys.tables' %(DB_name)
        command = 'sqlcmd -S "%s" -Q "%s"' %(Instance_name, query)

        execute_query = self.session.run_cmd(command)
        if execute_query.std_err:
            print "Error in command execution :- ", execute_query.std_err
            return False
        with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(execute_query.std_out)
        return output_file

  def get_db_Schema(self, Instance_name, DB_name):
    '''
    Get the schema of all tables in the Database
    '''
    table_list = self.get_table_list_in_DB(Instance_name, DB_name)
    flag = 0
    db_schema = {}

    with open(table_list, 'r') as f1:
        for lines in f1:
            if re.match("^\s", lines):
                flag = 0
            if flag:
                table_schema = self.get_table_Schema(
                    Instance_name, DB_name, table_name=lines.strip())
                db_schema.update(table_schema)
            if re.match("^----+?-", lines):
                flag = 1
    print db_schema
    return db_schema


def get_table_Schema(self, Instance_name, DB_name, table_name):
    '''
    Get the table schema
    '''
    table_schema = {}
    query = """
    SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE,
    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, IS_NULLABLE
    FROM [%s].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '%s'""".replace('\n','') %(DB_name, table_name)

    command = 'sqlcmd -S "%s" -Q "%s"' %(Instance_name, query)

    execute_query = self.session.run_cmd(command)
    table_schema[table_name] = execute_query.std_out
    if execute_query.std_err:
        print "Error in command execution :- ", execute_query.std_err
        return False
    return table_schema

def get_db_data(self, Instance_name, DB_name):
    '''
    From the given DB, it fetchs the data of all existing
    tables and append those in a single text file
    '''
    db_data = {}
    table_list = self.get_table_list_in_DB(Instance_name, DB_name)

    flag = 0
    with open(table_list, 'r') as f1:
        for lines in f1:
            if re.match("^\s", lines):
                flag = 0
            if flag:
                table_data = self.get_table_data(
                    Instance_name, DB_name, table_name=lines.strip())
                db_data.update(table_data)
            if re.match("^----+?-", lines):    # after the line ------ the tabel data are printed
                flag = 1

    print db_data
    return db_data

def get_table_data(self, Instance_name, DB_name, table_name):
    '''
    Get the data for the given table
    '''
    table_data = {}

    query = "SELECT * from [%s].dbo.[%s]" %(DB_name, table_name)
    command = 'sqlcmd -S "%s" -Q "%s"' %(Instance_name, query)
    execute_query = self.session.run_cmd(command)
    table_data[table_name] = execute_query.std_out
    if execute_query.std_err:
        print "Error in command execution :- ", execute_query.std_err
        return False
    return table_data

def compare_DB_Data(self, DB_Detail1=[], DB_Detail2=[]):
    '''
     Take detail of two DBs as input and gets the detailed DB data
     The data collected are dumped into one dictionary and at last
     both the dictionary are compared.

     Arguments :-
     DB_Detail1 :- a list of instance name and DB name for original DB
     DB_Detail2 :- a list of instance name and DB name for Restored DB
     e.g :- DB_Detail1 = ['Instance_name', 'Database_name']
    '''

    # Compare schema
    db_schema1 = self.get_db_Schema(
        Instance_name=DB_Detail1[0], DB_name=DB_Detail1[1])
    db_schema2 = self.get_db_Schema(
        Instance_name=DB_Detail2[0], DB_name=DB_Detail2[1])
    schema1_diff_schema2 = {}
    schema2_diff_schema1 = {}


    print db_schema1
    print db_schema2
    set_current, set_past = set(db_schema1.keys()), set(db_schema2.keys())
    intersect = set_current.intersection(set_past)
    added = set_current - intersect
    removed = set_past - intersect
    changed = set(k for k in intersect if db_schema2[k] != db_schema1[k])
    unchanged = set(k for k in intersect if db_schema2[k] == db_schema1[k])
    print added,removed,changed,unchanged

    [schema1_diff_schema2.update(i) for i in [{m :db_schema1[m]} for m in added ]]
    [schema1_diff_schema2.update(i) for i in [{m :db_schema1[m]} for m in changed]]
    [schema2_diff_schema1.update(i) for i in [{m :db_schema2[m]} for m in removed]]
    [schema2_diff_schema1.update(i) for i in [{m :db_schema2[m]} for m in changed]]

    if added ==  set([]) and removed == set([]) and changed == set([]):
        print "Schema of both DB Matches"
    else:
        print "Schema of both DB Varies"


    # Compare data
    data_DB1 = self.get_db_data(
        Instance_name=DB_Detail1[0], DB_name=DB_Detail1[1])
    data_DB2 = self.get_db_data(
        Instance_name=DB_Detail2[0], DB_name=DB_Detail2[1])
    data1_diff_data2 = {}
    data2_diff_data1 = {}

    set_current_data, set_past_data = set(data_DB1.keys()), set(data_DB2.keys())
    intersect = set_current_data.intersection(set_past_data)
    added = set_current_data - intersect
    removed = set_past_data - intersect
    changed = set(k for k in intersect if data_DB2[k] != data_DB1[k])
    unchanged = set(k for k in intersect if data_DB2[k] == data_DB1[k])
    print added,removed,changed,unchanged


    [data1_diff_data2.update(i) for i in [{m :data_DB1[m]} for m in added ]]
    [data1_diff_data2.update(i) for i in [{m :data_DB1[m]} for m in changed]]
    [data2_diff_data1.update(i) for i in [{m :data_DB2[m]} for m in removed]]
    [data2_diff_data1.update(i) for i in [{m :data_DB2[m]} for m in changed]]

    print "Diff DB1 vs DB2 :- ", data1_diff_data2
    print "Diff DB1 vs DB2 :- ", data2_diff_data1

    if added ==  set([]) and removed == set([]) and changed == set([]):
        print "Data of both DB Matches"
    else:
        print "Data of both DB Varies"
```